# Why id and itemId works differently in this code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Code:

```
const Game = () => {
  const [itemId, setItemId] = useState('');
  const [letters, setLetter] = useState([]);

   const handleItemClick = (id) => {
       letters[letters.length - 1] === 'H' ? setLetters([...letters, 'L']) :
          setLetters([...letters, 'H']);

       setItemId(id);
   }

   return (
      <div class="app">
         <ul>
             {
                [...Array(9)].map((_, idx) => {
                    return (
                       <Item
                          letters={letters}
                          handleSquareClick={handleItemClick}
                          id={idx}
                          itemId={itemId}
                        />
                     )
                })
             }
         </ul>
      </div>
    )
}
```

`Item` component

```
const Item = ({letters, handleItemClick, id, itemId }) => {
    return (
        <li
            onClick={() => handleItemClick(id)}
        >
          //the problem is here  
          //letters[id] returns different result from letters[itemId]
        </li>
    )
}
```

Why using `letters[itemId]` in `Item` Component make all `li`'s receive 'H' letter with one item click, while `letters[id]` make li's receive value one by one with every click

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-sky-sb2o0?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue is :

Because itemId is same all of your `<Item>` , single value is being shared with all `<Item>`

And `idx` which is index and is diff for all the `<Item>`

```
const [letters, setLetters] = useState([]);
const [itemId, setItemId] = useState(null);

const handleItemClick = id => {
    letters[letters.length - 1] === "H"
      ? setLetters([...letters, "L"])
      : setLetters([...letters, "H"]);
    setItemId(id); // <---- itemId is being set from here
};

{[...Array(9)].map((_, idx) => { // <----- idx coming from here, and is index
    return (
        <Item
            letters={letters}
            handleItemClick={handleItemClick}
            id={idx} // <--- this is index, comes diff for all item
            itemId={itemId} // <--- you are passing same value for all item
        />
    );
})}
```

You can replace the Item component with below one and check both values

```
const Item = ({ letters, id, itemId, handleItemClick }) => {
  return <li onClick={() => handleItemClick(id)}>idx : {idx} and item Id : {itemId} ---> {letters[itemId]}</li>;
};
```

**Please check this :**

[image: Edit #SO-generate-issue]

Comment: Thank you for answer, i still can't understand, both should be treated are just a number, index, i think element won't know if that number is the same or different in element?

Comment: @CodeEagle, I have created a codesandbox to show the issue, please review that I think that will make clear

Answer (score 2):

The reason why is because `itemId` is a fixed number (e. g. `3`) and the value at `letters[3]` is the same throughout the entire loop.  Whereas, `id` is set to the current `idx` of the 9-count loop and so is different for each `Item`.

```js
const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
const currentItemId = 0;

// Logs `1` 9 times
[...Array(9)].forEach((_, idx) => console.log(data[currentItemId])

// Logs `1` through `9`
[...Array(9)].forEach((_, idx) => console.log(data[idx])
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably because of this assignment `letters[letters.length - 1] = 'H'` you are getting this unexpected behavior. You probably needs to use the equal or Strict equal operator `letters[letters.length - 1] === 'H'`

Comment: sorry it is just a typo here, but you can see the strict equal operator in codesandbox l